# Can't set Android emulator date - stuck on 1/1/1970

Tags: shell, date-and-time, emulators, virtualization

I am having trouble manually setting the date on my android emulator.

I am using an ARM AVD which is running on a Windows 10 Virtual Machine (no Intel HAXM available), and the emulator is being run with the "-gpu swiftshader" option.

I tried setting the date both from the Android UI (the settings menu) and from the shell (adb date -s command with root privileges) with no success. The date keeps beeing stuck on 1/1/1970.

I Also tried changing my AVD's and the Android versions. I tried it on Android versions 2.3, 4.2, and 4.4. None of them worked.

What might be the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
I had the same problem.
I resolved checking "Snapshot" in Emulator Options (in Android Virtual Device Manager).
When you launch the Emulator you'll see your current date and time.